# Partial Derivatives of numbers not evaluating?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, numerical-value

I have code of the form

```
someFunction[xx_?VectorQ] := 1 + anotherFunction[xx]
myfunction[xx_?VectorQ]:= Sum[D[someFunction,xx[[a]]],{a,1,4}]
```

After this evaluates, it shows terms like $\partial_11$ and $\partial_20$, which doesn't make any sense.  (This isn't literally my code, it's just a simpler version of what I'm doing)

Why is it doing this, and how can I make it stop doing this?

---

Update: To make the calculation more concrete, I'll include the actual definition, which is significantly more complicated than the example

```
tLL[orderG_][xx_?VectorQ] := 
 Block[{gothOrderG, lowerOrderG, upperOrderG},
  gothOrderG = gothicG[orderG][xx];
  lowerOrderG = lowerG[orderG][xx];
  upperOrderG = upperG[orderG][xx];
  Table[Collect[Normal@Series[
  Sum[Sum[
    D[gothOrderG[[a, b]], xx[[l]]]*D[gothOrderG[[l, m]], xx[[m]]]
     - 
     D[gothOrderG[[a, l]], xx[[l]]]*
      D[gothOrderG[[b, m]], xx[[m]]]
     + 
     1/2 upperOrderG[[a, b]]*lowerOrderG[[l, m]]*
      Sum[Sum[D[gothOrderG[[l, n]], xx[[r]]]*
         D[gothOrderG[[m, r]], xx[[n]]], {r, 1, 4}], {n, 1, 4}]
     - 
     Sum[upperOrderG[[a, l]]*
       Sum[lowerOrderG[[m, n]]*D[gothOrderG[[b, n]], xx[[r]]], {n,
          1, 4}]*D[gothOrderG[[m, r]], xx[[l]]], {r, 1, 4}]
     - 
     Sum[upperOrderG[[b, l]]*
       Sum[lowerOrderG[[m, n]]*D[gothOrderG[[a, n]], xx[[r]]], {n,
          1, 4}]*D[gothOrderG[[m, r]], xx[[l]]], {r, 1, 4}]
     + 
     1/8 (2 upperOrderG[[a, l]]*upperOrderG[[b, m]] - 
        upperOrderG[[a, b]]*upperOrderG[[l, m]])
      *Sum[Sum[Sum[Sum[
          (2*lowerOrderG[[n, r]]*lowerOrderG[[s, t]] - 
             lowerOrderG[[r, s]]*lowerOrderG[[n, t]])
           * D[gothOrderG[[n, t]], xx[[l]]]*
           D[gothOrderG[[r, s]], xx[[m]]]
          , {t, 1, 4}], {s, 1, 4}], {r, 1, 4}], {n, 1, 4}]
    , {l, 1, 4}], {m, 1, 4}]
  , {G, 0, orderG}], G], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 1, 4}]
  ]
```

Where `gothicG`, `upperG`, and `lowerG` are all fairly cost-intensive matrix functions. Then when I call

```
tLL[0][{t, x, y, z}][[1, 1]]
```

it evaluates as $$\frac{1}{8} ( (\partial_1(-1)^2-6(\partial_10)^2 + 2(\partial_20)^2+\text{several other terms}$$.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[someFunction, myfunction, q, r, s, t]

someFunction[xx_?VectorQ] := 1 + anotherFunction[xx]
```

`someFunction` must be called with an argument.  And, since derivatives will be with respect to the elements of that argument, the elements must be symbols.

```
myfunction[xx_?VectorQ] := Sum[D[someFunction[xx], xx[[a]]], {a, 1, 4}]

f1 = myfunction[{q, r, s, t}]
```

[image]

`myfunction` can be defined more succinctly as

```
Clear[myfunction]

myfunction[xx_?VectorQ] := D[someFunction[xx], {xx}] // Total

f2 = myfunction[{q, r, s, t}]
```

[image]

Verifying equivalence of definitions

```
f1 == f2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, let me try to fix it better.  What I really have is more like `myFunction[xx_?VectorQ]:=Block[{foo}, foo=someFunction[xx]; D[foo, Sum[D[foo, xx[[a]] ], {a,1,4}]`, and I have `foo` defined earlier in a block because it is fairly cost-intensive to calculate and I actually use it several different times.  When I evaluate, I type `myFunction[{t,x,y,z}]`, and still get the weird partials.

Comment: I should note that if I just type `foo=someFunction[{t,x,y,z}]; D[foo,x]` not inside of a block or function definition, then I get the correct results.  Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: It is a scoping issue. It is generally better to use explicit arguments in the definition to avoid potential scoping conflicts when calling the function.

Comment: I found the error!  And it was a scope issue.  I had t as a dummy index inside one of the sums, and also as a coordinate name.